# Add a new value in a list of data in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have data containing records and I want to update the list with new figures of sales values for all authors. This is going to increase the length of the list in Sales so that the numbers of books sold for each author becomes last year's figure and so on.

```
data T = T { Author  :: String
           , Sales :: [Int]
           , Year :: Int}
    deriving Show
```

My attempt

```
addNewValues :: [data] -> [Int] -> [data]
addNewValues  (m:ms) (x:xs) = let (author, sales, year)  addNewValues ms xs
```

I realise this is not correct and incomplete but as a beginner I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the inputs and output that you want for `addNewValues`?

Comment: For example if I had a value such as  [("Jennifer Aeker", 2948, 2009)]  I would give new sales value 5385, addNewValues [("Jennifer Aeker", 5385, 2009)] and in the new record I would then have the new and old [("Jennifer Aeker", 5385, 2948, 2009)]

Comment: In your question, you have `[Int]` as the type of the second and third fields, but in your comment, you only have a single integer and not a list. (And in your latest edit to your comment, you have 3 numbers, but it's not apparent which should be in each list.)

Comment: Sorry, that was only an example so I didn't add more values in my comment.

Comment: Isn't each record only going to have one year, not a list of years? Why did you make that an `[Int]` then?

Comment: My mistake, I corrected it!

Comment: Also, custom data types are a different thing than tuples. You seem to be using tuple syntax despite declaring a custom data type. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: Custom data types is what I want to use.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, variables start with lowercase letters and constructors start with uppercase letters. `Author`, `Sales`, and `Year` are variables, so first change them to start with lowercase letters:

```
data T = T { author  :: String
           , sales :: [Int]
           , year :: Int}
    deriving Show
```

Also, `data` is a keyword that defines a type, not the type itself, so you want to use `T` instead of `data` in your function's type signature:

```
addNewValues :: [T] -> [Int] -> [T]
```

Another key point is that custom data types are not tuples, so you can't use tuple syntax with them. Using record update syntax instead looks like this:

```
addNewValues  (m:ms) (x:xs) = m{ sales = x:sales m }:addNewValues ms xs
```

The last thing you need is a case to terminate the recursion, so you don't get an error at the end of the lists:

```
addNewValues _ _ = []
```

And here's an example of using it:

```
Prelude> addNewValues [T "Jennifer Aeker" [2948] 2009] [5385]
[T {author = "Jennifer Aeker", sales = [5385,2948], year = 2009}]
```

Or if you did want to use tuples instead of a custom type, you could replace the type and cons case with these lines:

```
type T = (String, [Int], Int)
addNewValues  (m:ms) (x:xs) = let (author, sales, year) = m in (author, x:sales, year):addNewValues ms xs
```

If you're still learning Haskell, the next thing you should look into is the `zipWith` function, which would let you make all of that a bit neater.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I were to use custom data type like this: type Author  = String       type = Sales [int]    type Year = Int.      Type Record = (Author, Sales, Year) , can I still use Sales in my code like you did? Because when I tried I just got  parse error on input 'Sales'

Comment: @buzzyso `type` defines aliases, not custom data types. `data` defines custom data types.